# Wget does not recognize directory on ftp

Tags: wget

I need a help with the Wget command in linux, ubuntu.
I am using this command on an ftp site ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/viral/

The command is as follows:

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/file.txt); do wget -r $i/latest_assembly_versions/; done
```

The error:
The file "GCA_003146765.1_ASM314676v1" was not found

This file is actually a directory, and I do not know how to flag it.

Thank you!

Comment: put double quotes `"` around the variable `$i` like so `"$i"/latest_assembly_versions/` and may I ask if your trying to read from that file `/tmp/file.txt`

Comment: Yes, I am reading from /tmp/file.txt. The file.txt originates from: lynx --dump ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/viral/ | awk '/ftp/{print $2}' | grep "phage" > /tmp/file.txt

Comment: Try this fist put the cat value in another variable say `r=$(cat file.txt)`, then do `for i in "$r"; do wget -r "$i"/latest_assembly_versions/; done`. Watch out for white spaces in the file

Comment: the problem is not with the "file.txt" but with a directory that is below it on the ftp page. Exemple: " ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/viral/Acinetobacter_phage_AM24/latest_assembly_versions/GCA_002615385.1_ASM261538v1/". But this last directory (GCA_002615385.1_ASM261538v1) is erroneously read as a file